# How can show data from sql server in sharepoint 2013 without using list?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a table in SQL database.

```
R.No  Name  Address
 1    priya  tnj
 2    kavi   tnj
```

In SharePoint, I want to show above SQL table in a page without using list.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you want to use instead of list? Please provide some details of what you would like to do. You could create a JSON in C# or use javascript to connect to database, and then use html/javascript to display the data in a table inside a web page / part.

Comment: I want to store large amount of data. Anyway it may be possible with list. But i want to show the data using any available services in sql

Comment: In detail, I created a page named "UserList". In this page i want show the above table. For this, how can I use services(like reporting services, intergration services....) which are available in sql? Or any other way? But I don't want list. Because it have draw back when store huge data. Shall you expalin?

Comment: What's wrong with using a list? A list can have an external content type, which allows you to have your data in an external source, such as SQL Server.  More info on external content types [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163139.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

On Sharepoint foundation without custom coding you cannot do it. (in Enterprise you have BDC that could achieve that or  you could use infopath). In your case create an web part (it can have properties like: connection, query. Retrieve the data transform and display to your harts content.

Comment: Shall you explain in detail? i.e, which web part is used in this case

Comment: That is a bit too much to explain in detail. I had in mind custom web part. You fire off visual studio create web part with custom code (so establish connection to SQL transform and display the way you like it) I prefer custom web part as I can avoid overhead that out of the box webparts bring. But I guess you could use data view web part to achive what you want using SPDesigner. Have a look at this article: https://bssharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/display-external-sql-data-via-dataview-web-part/